# How to "inject" a property and its value to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

"Inject" a property and its value to an object.

### The problem

I have the following object that is created by Entity Framework 5:

```
public partial class getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public string measureAbbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

I'm creating a Shopping List using Session and when an user adds something to his list, the application calls a procedure to get the information about this product and these information populate the above properties respectively.

The point is: the user can add the the amount of products he wants — and it is not responsibility of the database.

To add a product, the user must to access `MyApp.com/Products/Add?productId=1&quantity=5`. I can retrieve all the information about the product using this:

***ShoppingListController.cs***:

```
public ActionResult Add(Nullable<int> productId, int quantity)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        Session["ShoppingList"] = new 
           List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>();
    }

    getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result product = 
      Products.BuildItemToShoppingList(productId);

    ((List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>)Session["ShoppingList"])
      .Add(product);

    return View("Index");
}
```

And then, the ***view***:

```
@foreach (var item in 
    (List<MyApp.Models.Data.getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>)
    Session["ShoppingList"])
{
    <p>@item.productName | @item.measureAbbreviation</p>
}
```

My question is simple: how can I add something like `@item.quantity`?

### What I'm thinking about

I'm thinking in something like this (pay attention to line after product variable declaration):

```
public ActionResult Add(Nullable<int> productId, int quantity)
{
    if (Session["ShoppingList"] == null)
    {
        Session["ShoppingList"] = 
          new List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>();
    }

    getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result product = 
      Products.BuildItemToShoppingList(productId);

    ((List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>)Session["ShoppingList"])
      .Insert(productId, 
         new KeyValuePair<string, int>("quantity", quantity))
      .Add(product);

    return View("Index");
}
```

But — of course — no success. The syntax is wrong, but was just to illustrate.

### Details

I'm using C#.Net + MVC 4 + Razor Engine

Comment: *"Add property to an object."* What do you ***really*** mean? Add a new item to a list that's stored in session?

Comment: I'm calling the information about a product using `@item.productName` on the view. I want to call the quantity added by the user using `@item.quantity` — and the quantity has no relation with the object itself. I mean, I want to inject "`@item.quantity`" to the "`product`" variable, that is an object.

Comment: the `class` is `partial`. add the property, `Quantity`, to the `partial class`. fwiw, there's, most probably, a much better solution to this.

Comment: @Xander The point is: *how?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same namespace as your entity framework model, ie. the same folder you put the .edmx file, make a new Class with the same name as the class the one defined in the entity framework, which I think in your case is `getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result`.

Mark the class as partial, and you can add properties of your own to it.

Eg: you have this in your .edmx designer file:

```
    [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="YourModel", Name="getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result : EntityObject
    {
...
    }
```

This is auto generated and you can't alter it to add some properties, but it's marked as partial to let you expand on it, eg. if I add:

```
public partial class getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result
{
    public int Quantity {get; set; }
}
```

C# joins them together, so in my controller, I can do

`var something = new List<getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result>();`

`something.First().quantity = 50;`

Quantity doesn't belong to getSpecificProductToShoppingList_Result because that is my database type, but I have added it via a partial class.

Comment: Yes, you're creating a new class with the same name that is partial, which you can put your properties in eg. `int quantity {get; set;}` then both classes will be joined together and behave as a single class.

Comment: @SLC I can't — duplicate file name. Maybe "inject" the property into the partial class can solve?

Comment: Not sure why you have a duplicate file name, perhaps it's a template problem, just change the filename but keep the class name the same as the entity one

Comment: PERFECT! Not only worked as I understand the concept. Amazing explanation! Thank you very much!